# SQL Diff software that support SQL Server 2012 - any recommendations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

In a previous work place we worked with a software called SQL Delta which compared 2 sql servers - so we could sync the changes from our development machine and the production machine. I checked and they don't seem to support SQL Server 2012 yet.

Does anyone have any recommendation about another SQL Diff software that works with SQL Server 2012, has a good easy and clear interface?

An advantage is that it will also support SQL Server Azure.

Thanks

Comment: While this was closed, note that *no* software will directly be able to diff with Azure SQL (which is different than SQL Server on Azure). This is because Azure SQL does *not* expose the required "reflection" mechanisms. Scripted diffs can be pushed .. but the diff has to be done against a real SQL Server source.

Comment: The tools built into VS 2012 database project will allow you to do it, as will RedGate Compare tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try red-gate, this also support sql server 2012

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/features

also:

http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner/

and

[dbforge](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/download.html?utm_source=schemacomparereview&utm_medium=download&utm_campaign=cc_SQL_Authority)

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [xSQL](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_data_compare/), I had used their free version sometime back and found it to be pretty good.